# How to solve pthread_create error (11) resource temporarily unavailable?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, openwrt

I'm building a project in c language (using openwrt as OS) to upload files to FTP server. and i'm using MQTT for the incoming data. So for each topic i subscribe to, i save this data and then upload it to the FTP server and to keep things going smoothly, each time i need to upload a file i just use a thread to do the job.
and to make sure the program doesn't run too much threads, each topic is allowed to create one thread. and i'm using a variable (like mutex but it's not pthread_mutex_t because i don't need to block a thread, i want to skip that step and upload the next file). i though with this technique i'm safe but after running the program for 15 min i get this error 11 which said resource temporarily unavailable when the program try to create a thread (pthread_create).
one of my tries to figure out what could be the problem is.

- i used the pthread_join() function which is not an option in my condition but just to make sure that each thread is finished and not running in permanent loop. the program was running over than an hour and the error didn't show up again. and of course each thread was finished as intended.
- and i'm 90% sure that each topic is creating only on thread and the next one will be create only if the previous one finished. (i was tracking the status of the variable before and after the thread creation).
- i set the max thread from here "/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max" to 2000 (2000 is more than enough since i don't have too much topics)

upload function (this will create the thread):

```
void uploadFile(<args...>, bool* locker_p){
    *locker_p = true;
    args->uploadLocker_p = uploadLocker_p;

    <do something here>

    pthread_t tid;
    int error = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, uploadFileThread, (void*)args);
        if(0 != error){
            printf("Couldn't run thread,(%d) => %s\n", error, strerror(error));
    }
        else{
            printf("Thread %d\n", tid);
    }
}
```

upload thread:

```
void *uploadFileThread(void *arg){ 
    typeArgs* args = (typeArgs*)arg;

   <do something like upload the file>

    *(args->uploadLocker_p) = false;
    free(args);

    return NULL;
    //pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: 90% == you don't know for sure. Get the pid of your process and do "watch 'ls /proc/<pid>/task'" and see if that number shoots up.

Comment: watch is not found, i can't display how many threads the program is running. i was looking for days how to display them or at least track it by ps or anything else, nothing works, i'm limited to what this OS have. and i just didn't want to say 100% but any whay, i'm confident it's only one thread per topic.

Comment: put a printf when your threads start and one when they finish and see if they match up. You don;t have to have watch, but you should know that /proc/<pid> has all the information you need, /proc/sys/kernel is for kernel wide settings, you should check your process limits there

Comment: i think this is the max thread per process, i found it in the limits file for my process which is " Max processes: 982 "
and the folder /proc/<pid>/task/ has only one folder whith same pid. ( is the task folder holds all thread and each one by it's pid.?)

Comment: yeah task folder has the pid of all threads, including the parent...if you only see one, then you havent seen any of the children yet, maybe you need to repeat ls a few times to check that you see what you expect to see (this is what watch does)

Comment: already did that. and to answer your previous question, i did some printf to track the thread when started and finished.
and i tried to change the process field (when you type "ulimit" and the max is 982.
i counted the files i upload to folder , they are around 1015 file which mean 1015 was created.
i have a question, when i create a thread, and then after it finish, i create another one, does that count as 1 thread or 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default stack size for the created threads is eating too much virtual memory.

Essentially, the kernel is telling your process that it has so much virtual memory already in use that it doesn't dare give it any more, because there isn't enough RAM and swap to back it up if the process were to suddenly use it all.

To fix, create an attribute that limits the per-thread stack to something sensible. If your threads do not use arrays as local variables, or do deep recursion, then `2*PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` (from `<limits.h>`) is a good size.
The attribute is not consumed by the `pthread_create()` call, it is just a configuration block, and you can use the same one for any number of threads you create, or create a new one for each thread.

Example:

```
pthread_attr_t  attrs;
pthread_t       tid;
int             err;

pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, 2 * PTHREAD_STACK_MIN);
err = pthread_create(&tid, &attrs, uploadFileThread, (void *)args);
pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
if (err) {
    /* Failed, errno in err; use strerror(err) */
} else {
    /* Succeeded */
}
```

Also remember that if your `uploadFileThread()` allocates memory, it will not be freed automatically when the thread exits.  It looks like OP already knows this (as they have the function free the argument structure when it's ready to exit), but I thought it a good idea to point it out.

---

Personally, I like to use a thread pool instead.  The idea is that the upload workers are created beforehand, and they'll wait for a new job.  Here is an example:

```
pthread_mutex_t        workers_lock;
pthread_mutex_t        workers_wait;
volatile struct work  *workers_work;
volatile int           workers_idle;
volatile sig_atomic_t  workers_exit = 0;
```

where `struct work` is a singly-linked list protected by `workers_lock`, `workers_idle` is initialized to zero and incremented when waiting for new work, `workers_wait` is a condition variable signaled when new work arrives under `workers_lock`, and `workers_exit` is a counter that when nonzero, tells that many workers to exit.

A worker would be basically something along

```
void worker_do(struct work *job)
{
   /* Whatever handling a struct job needs ... */
}

void *worker_function(void *payload __attribute__((unused)))
{
    /* Grab the lock. */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_lock);

    /* Job loop. */
    while (!workers_exit) {
        if (workers_work) {
            /* Detach first work in chain. */
            struct work *job = workers_work;
            workers_work = job->next;
            job->next = NULL;

            /* Work is done without holding the mutex. */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_lock);
            worker_do(job);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_lock);
            continue;
        }

        /* We're idle, holding the lock. Wait for new work. */
        ++workers_idle;
        pthread_cond_wait(&workers_wait, &workers_lock);
        --workers_idle;
    }

    /* This worker exits. */
    --workers_exit;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_lock);
    return NULL;
}
```

The connection handling process can use `idle_workers()` to check the number of idle workers, and either grow the worker thread pool, or reject the connection as being too busy.  The `idle_workers()` is something like

```
static inline int  idle_workers(void)
{
    int  result;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_lock);
    result = workers_idle;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_lock);
    return result;
}
```

Note that each worker only holds the lock for very short durations, so the `idle_workers()` call won't block for long. (`pthread_cond_wait()` atomically releases the lock when it starts waiting for a signal, and only returns after it re-acquires the lock.)

When waiting for a new connection in `accept()`, set the socket nonblocking and use `poll()` to wait for new connections.  If the timeout passes, examine the number of workers, and reduce them if necessary by calling `reduce_workers(1)` or similar:

```
void reduce_workers(int number)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_lock);
    if (workers_exit < number) {
        workers_exit = number;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&workers_wait);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_lock);
}
```

To avoid having to call `pthread_join()` for each thread – and we really don't even know which threads have exited here! – to reap/free the kernel and C library metadata related to the thread, the worker threads need to be *detached*.  After creating a worker thread `tid` successfully, just call `pthread_detach(tid);`.

When a new connection arrives and it is determined to be one that should be delegated to the worker threads, you *can*, but do not have to, check the number of idle threads, create new worker threads, reject the upload, or just append the work to the queue, so that it will "eventually" be handled.

Comment: thank you. i will try both of your methods and i will give you my feedback as soon as i finish.

Comment: @shadow: In case you missed it, if you do not `pthread_join()` threads that have completed their work (returned), you need to detach them when you create them (via `pthread_detach(tid)` immediately after `pthread_create()`, or otherwise some internal C library and kernel data structures are left to linger, wasting resources.

Comment: thank you so much, i think this is what i'm missing the whole time, i will test this first because i need a quick solution for now and then i will give a shot the other methods .because i think it's better to use a thread pool instead of create a thread for each upload. i will keep you up to date. thank you again

Comment: the missing part was pthread_detach(tid), thank you @Example. and for the pool thread, i don't think i need it because i'm only using one thread for FTP that i can control via mutex and the condition signal and in my condition i don't want a stack of jobs to be done, if the FTP is uploading file, then any other file will be ignored. so i guess i will use something similar to pool thread but only with waiting list equal to 1.